# Download pdf in android 11

Tags: java, android, file, download, android-11

I have upgraded to android 11. I am having an issue downloading PDF files.

I have used this code:

```
private void createFile(Uri pickerInitialUri, String title) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker when your app creates the document.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
}
```

The file is created but the file is empty. I am still unable to save the downloaded pdf file.

I used to use DownloadManager request to download the pdf file from web.

````
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        if (SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

         //   Uri uri1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), ""));  //before android 11 this was working fine

           // Uri uri1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "")); 

            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setTitle(title + strDate + ".pdf")
                    .setDescription(description)
                    //.setDestinationUri(uri1) // before android 11 it was working fine.
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title + strDate + ".pdf") // file is not saved on this directory.
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);//to show the DOWNLOAD notification when completed

           // createFile(uri , title + strDate + ".pdf"); // for new scoped storage


        } else {
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setTitle(title + strDate + ".pdf")
                    .setDescription(description)
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(FileUtils.downloadPdfDestination(), title + strDate + ".pdf")
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //to show the DOWNLOAD notification when completed
        }
       long PDF_DOWNLOAD_ID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);```
````

Comment: It makes no sense to first create an empty file with action create document and then download a file with downloadmanager. The download manager will not need or use that empty file. So what is it that you have in mind?

Comment: I have used Download manager at first to download pdf and it worked. But after I upgraded to android 11. File downloaded from downloadmanager is not saved. I am confused by scoped storage to download pdf file.

Comment: Your problem makes no sense. The code should just do its job like before. No problems here.

Comment: I have tried it. File was not saved. I dont know how the problem occured. I am also trying to solve it. It works fine for mobile below android 10 but mobile device with android 11 does not work.

Comment: `FileUtils.downloadPdfDestination()` I already told you that that destination (`Android/data`) is not usable on an Android 11 device. That code is unusable. Sorry that i first told you that it was ok. (Should have looked better... but why should we know what FileUtils.downloadPdfDestination() returns.) You were not informative..

Comment: `strDate` We cannot see how that string value looks like. Please add more code. Also tell value of `title + strDate + ".pdf"`

Comment: FileUtils.downloadPdfDestination() - this code is used for below android 11. title is random text and strdate is date format.

Comment: I did not ask for format. I asked for exact value.

Answer (score 1):

ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT is used to create a new document.  If one already existed, it will be overwritten.  If you want to view an existing document, use ACTION_VIEW.

Of course none of the code you posted actually downloads a PDF.  If you need help with that, post your DownloadManager code.

Comment: I have posted my download manger code.

Answer (score -1):

Check this code snippet:

```
override fun startDownload(url: String, onError: (e: Exception) -> Unit) {
        try {
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            )
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION)
            (context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager).enqueue(request)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            onError.invoke(e)
        }
    }
```

It's working fine on `Android 11` by using `DownloadManger` API.

Comment: This is not working. I have used this code. It only shows file has downloaded but file cannot be found on files folder.

Comment: In files folder? In Download folder you mean. Well.. if your code tells you it is downloaded and saved, it should be there i think. Please tell where things go wrong.

Comment: I checked the location where the file was downloaded but there was no file. File was saved on /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Downloads.  But inside Android/Data no folder was created. I don't know where it went wrong here.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Downloads` That indeed is an impossible parh on an Android 11 device. Why such a strange location? Nibody uses that. Why would you? Normal would be `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. Like Romman does. How could you say that it was not in that Download directory?

Comment: `I checked the location where the file was downloaded ` ??? How woud you even check that location on an Android 11 device.? You have no access to begin with.

Comment: For Android >Q you already use /storage/emulated/0/Download looking at your code. You are quite confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code to download & view pdf.

First you need to apply **`rxjava`** dependency for background task.

```
 implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

Don't forgot to check **`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`** permission before call below method. Also check **`INTERNET`** permission as well.

Then use below method to perform operation in background.

```
private void downloadAndOpenInvoice() {
    mDialog.show();
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        String pdfName = "Invoice_"+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".pdf";
        
        String pdfUrl = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
        
        File file = CommonUtils.downloadFile(mActivity, pdfUrl, pdfName,mDialog);
        return file;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(file -> {
                CommonUtils.viewPdf(file, mActivity, mDialog);
            });
}
```

To download file from url use below snippet

```
public static File downloadFile(Activity mActivity, String url, String fileName, CustomDialog mDialog) {
    // write the document content
    File fileDir = new File(CommonUtils.getAppDir(mActivity, "Invoice")); //Invoice folder inside your app directory 
    if (!fileDir.exists()) {
        boolean mkdirs = fileDir.mkdirs();
    }
    File pdfFile = new File(CommonUtils.getAppDir(mActivity, "Invoice"), fileName); //Invoice folder inside your app directory

    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return pdfFile;
}
```

for app directory

```
public static String getAppDir(Context context, String folderName) {
    return context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + folderName + File.separator;
}
```

Use below code to view pdf

```
public static void viewPdf(File pdfFile, Activity mActivity, CustomDialog mDialog) {

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, mActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", pdfFile);

    // Setting the intent for pdf reader
    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    //pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    try {
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        mActivity.startActivity(pdfIntent);
        Log.e("Invoice - PDF", pdfFile.getPath());
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Invoice - PDF", "Can't read pdf file");
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Can't read pdf file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! But this code did not help me with android 11 devices.   
"( return context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + folderName + File.separator;)" This code is not working for android 11 device.

Comment: @AnishMaharjan Can you please tell what error coming with above code ? You can find pdf file inside your app package in file manager.

Comment: The file is not saved. Download manager shows the file is downloaded. But the file cannot be found inside the file manager. Is there any new permission required in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you need to check WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission first. Also add this permission into manifest.